# Show last uploaded Image of specified Google Drive Folder on Website / Spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-sheets, directory, embedding

I wanted to give a list of users an easy way to upload and display their Image to a website.
An extremly convenient way of uploading is, of course, a google drive folder. 
So is it possible to display the newest file of a google drive folder in either - a website - or in google spreadsheet document? Php would be fine, too.

Comment: images in your google drive, or the users own?

Comment: In a shared Google drive folder

Comment: google drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple ways to do this.  First, you need to determine what the last uploaded image file was.  So, the image would need a date and time stamp that can be retrieved, or some other way to figure out what the last image uploaded is.  You could save the file with some kind of time stamp in the file name, or put something in the file description.

Apps Script has something called HTML Service, which allows you to serve HTML in an application.

[Google Documentation HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/)

In other words, you can create a website with HTML.  The URL is a long address, so it won't be a typical website address.  Apps Scripts server side code is JavaScript, so you wouldn't be using PHP.  Google App Engine does have a free service, where you can use PHP, but the free service is not served over HTTPS.  (S on end.)  The free service is served with HTTP (No S on end.  Not encrypted)

So, I'm quite sure what you want to do is possible.  The option you decide on depends on what you want for features, and how much work you can or want to put into it.

In the long run, you might be better off with HTML Service than a spreadsheet or document.  If you already know some HTML, I don't see any point of trying to make a spreadsheet a website.

Do you have control over what the users name the image files they upload?  If the users are accessing the Drive directly, you have no control over what file info gets attributed to the file.  Google will automatically give the file a Created, Opened and Modified date, but I don't know if a time is recorded.  That won't help if you have more then one file uploaded a day to determine which one is the most recent.

There is a `getDateCreated()` method of the File Class.

If that includes the time, then you could use that to determine the last file uploaded.  There is also a way to watch a file for changes in Google Drive, but you need to watch the folder.  I doubt it would be good to put a watch on every file in the folder.

[Google Documentation - Get Date Created](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#getDateCreated())